# Understanding difference of potential in an AC circuit

Tags: ac

I have a circuit that takes 120 V AC fed into a transformer and puts out 24 V AC. The circuit uses a difference of potential to energize a relay and keep it closed using a holding circuit.

What I don’t understand is how the high voltage line can read anywhere from 18 VAC to 34 VAC, while the “low side” can read anywhere from 6 VAC to 10 VAC as long as the difference of potential equals 24 VAC. Is there a resource out there that I can read to explain this to me? This is my first time encountering a circuit like this.

I am using a multimeter set to AC with the black lead on a common ground, which is supplied from the neutral line of the 3-phase building power fed into the machine, and the other lead probing connections throughout the circuit. I usually use the output of the transformer X1, which is the low side, and X2, which is the high side to get my base measurements. What I don’t understand is why is there voltage in the low side of the circuit. And how can the high side vary so much?

Thank you for the answers. Unfortunately I can't share the schematic due to my contract. However, it appears that I am struggling with the fact that there is no common ground between the main circuit and the isolated one.

Comment: You need to explain how you made those measurements. Please note that asking for resources is not the correct use of this site (not a forum).

Comment: I think an image of the circuit would help immensely. From what I can tell it's down to stray capacitance.

Comment: @Jasonp, welcome to the site. It's important that all the information is in the **question**, not squirreled away in the comments. I've moved it in there for you. You may delete the comment.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQX0CG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Interpretation of the circuit.*

It sounds as though you are measuring voltages on an isolated circuit with reference to Earth / ground. As should be clear from the diagram, there is no return path from VM1 or VM2's Earth terminals to the secondary of the transformer. The voltages you are measuring are due to stray capacitance to ground on the transformer or on the isolated load or some leakage resistance.

For an isolated or floating supply you need to take one of the AC lines as ground for your measurements.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvOzng.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Neither of these measurements on an isolated battery are going to give you any useful information - other than that there is no ground reference on the battery.*

A simple analogy would be to measure the voltage between one terminal of a battery and ground. You wouldn't expect a valid reading because there is no return path through the meter to the other battery terminal.